# Asterisk 12 REST API (ARI) playback with no answer

Tags: asterisk

To process noanswer call and play audio in dialplan we should:

```
[default]
exten => _.,1,Progress()
same => n,Playback(filename, noanswer)
```

But if we use REST API, documentation says:

```
POST /channels/{channelId}/play

Path parameters
channelId: string - Channel's id
Query parameters
media: string - (required) Media's URI to play.
lang: string - For sounds, selects language for sound.
offsetms: int - Number of media to skip before playing.
skipms: int = 3000 - Number of milliseconds to skip for forward/reverse operations.
playbackId: string - Playback ID.
```

And there is no option "noanswer".

**Is there any posibility to playback audio from ARI without answering channel?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

import ari
import logging
import threading
import uuid

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)

client = ari.connect('http://localhost:8088', 'asterisk', 'asterisk')

channel_timers = {}

def stasis_end_cb(channel, ev):
    """Handler for StasisEnd event"""

    print "Channel %s just left our application" % channel.json.get('name')
    timer = channel_timers.get(channel.id)
    if timer:
        timer.cancel()
        del channel_timers[channel.id]

def stasis_start_cb(channel_obj, ev):
    """Handler for StasisStart event"""

    def answer_channel(channel, playback):
        """Callback that will actually answer the channel"""

        print "Answering channel %s" % channel.json.get('name')
        playback.stop()
        channel.answer()

        timer = threading.Timer(1, hangup_channel, [channel])
        channel_timers[channel.id] = timer
        timer.start()

    def hangup_channel(channel):
        """Callback that will actually hangup the channel"""

        print "Hanging up channel %s" % channel.json.get('name')
        channel.hangup()

    channel = channel_obj.get('channel')
    print "Channel %s has entered the application" % channel.json.get('name')

    playback_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    playback = channel.playWithId(playbackId=playback_id,
                                  media='tone:ring;tonezone=fr')
    timer = threading.Timer(8, answer_channel, [channel, playback])
    channel_timers[channel.id] = timer
    timer.start()


client.on_channel_event('StasisStart', stasis_start_cb)
client.on_channel_event('StasisEnd', stasis_end_cb)


client.run(apps='channel-tones')
```

From here - https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ARI+and+Channels%3A+Simple+Media+Manipulation

Comment: I mean Stasis controlled channed are not auto answered (unless there was a Answer in dialplan before sending to Stasis). See the example above.

Comment: The answer event makes automaticaly when in stasis U send "playback media:" to channel. After sending playback channel is answered/ In classic dialplan U can send playback with option "noanswer" and it is played in "progress" and channel stays unanswered.

Comment: I haven't found the way to send playback media in stasis and no to make channel answer.